# Downgrading OpenGL 4.5 code to OpenGL 3.0

Tags: c#, opengl, opengl-3, opengl-4

I found a repo to solve a problem I was having with OpenGL but it was all written in GL 4.5 and the application I'm writing needs to be GL 3.0 code for OSX support. I've been able to translate most of the code by referencing it on [docs.GL](https://docs.gl) and converting it back to 3.0 code that I'm familiar with.

I've struggled a bit with understanding the code below, so I was just wondering if anyone would be able to point me in the right direction.

`vertexArray`
`vertexBuffer`
`indexBuffer`
are all `int`

```
GL.VertexArrayVertexBuffer(vertexArray, 0, vertexBuffer, IntPtr.Zero, Unsafe.SizeOf<ImDrawVert>());
GL.VertexArrayElementBuffer(vertexArray, indexBuffer);

GL.EnableVertexArrayAttrib(vertexArray, 0);
GL.VertexArrayAttribBinding(vertexArray, 0, 0);
GL.VertexArrayAttribFormat(vertexArray, 0, 2, VertexAttribType.Float, false, 0);

GL.EnableVertexArrayAttrib(vertexArray, 1);
GL.VertexArrayAttribBinding(vertexArray, 1, 0);
GL.VertexArrayAttribFormat(vertexArray, 1, 2, VertexAttribType.Float, false, 8);

GL.EnableVertexArrayAttrib(vertexArray, 2);
GL.VertexArrayAttribBinding(vertexArray, 2, 0);
GL.VertexArrayAttribFormat(vertexArray, 2, 4, VertexAttribType.UnsignedByte, true, 16);
```

Edit: Im using [OpenTK](https://github.com/opentk/opentk) with C# if anyone was wondering.

Comment: "*the application I'm writing needs to be GL 3.0 code for OSX support*" MacOS supports GL 4.1 (assuming you have appropriate hardware). However, MacOS deprecated OpenGL and could remove it pretty much at any time. So you may want to avoid limiting yourself to such a platform.

Comment: Looks like [DSA](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Direct_State_Access) code to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles across this particular problem in future, I had to read the description of the GL 4.5 code and match it up to GL 3.0 code.

For this particular code snippet, it becomes:

```
GL.BindVertexArray(vertexArray);

GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertexBuffer);
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, indexBuffer);

GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Unsafe.SizeOf<ImDrawVert>(), 0);

GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Unsafe.SizeOf<ImDrawVert>(), 8);

GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(2);
GL.VertexAttribPointer(2, 4, VertexAttribPointerType.UnsignedByte, true, Unsafe.SizeOf<ImDrawVert>(), 16);
```